# Time zone for Gnome Top Bar Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: gnome-shell, time, clock, top-bar

Ubuntu 18.10

My Gnome Top Bar is displaying UTC time.  I want local time.

Ubuntu Time and Date Settings are correct and show Timezone: America/Chicago

$ date   shows the local time

I installed "Gnome Clock override" and can manipulate the format but not the timezone which should be -0600.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the hardware clock time standard to localtime, use do:

```
timedatectl set-local-rtc 1 --adjust-system-clock
```

and

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

If you want to revert to the hardware clock being in UTC, do:

```
timedatectl set-local-rtc 0 --adjust-system-clock
```

Check what you have set by:

```
timedatectl
```